# Is Morton's toe curable without surgery?

Tags: exercise, footwear, podiatry

Is it possible to cure Morton's toe without any surgery?  Does any exercise/footwear useful in treating Morton's toe?

Comment: What has your research revealed?

Comment: @CareyGregory I came to know that the pain(if occurs) due to Morton's toe can be reduced, but no information about the treatment of Morton's toe i.e., making thumb toe larger than the second toe.